# Error 500 when calling method in loopback using tfjs-node

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, loopbackjs

I am writing an API using loopback and am having issues with one of my methods. All methods work but one which returns "Error: only http(s) protocols are supported"

This is the method in question:

```
Engine.evaluateone = async function(container, name) {
    // Accepts image as a header of an array and converts to a tensor and processes
    const path = ('./server/storage/'+container+'/'+name+'.jpg');
    const network =  await tf.loadModel("file://./cnn/cnnmodel/model.json");
    const img = new Canvas.Image();
    const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(28, 28);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var response;
    img.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 28, 28);
      var tensor = tf.fromPixels(canvas, 1);
      tensor = loadAndProcessImage(tensor);
      tensor = tensor.reshape([1, 28, 28, 1]);
      var prediction = network.predict(tensor);
      const labelPrediction = prediction.as1D().argMax().dataSync()[0];
      response = [String.fromCharCode(labels[labelPrediction]), true]
    }
    img.src = path;
    return response;


    };

Engine.remoteMethod(
    'evaluateone', {
      http:
        {path: '/evaluateone', verb: 'post'},
      accepts: [
        {arg: 'container', type: 'string'},
        {arg: 'name', type: 'string'}
      ],
      returns: [
        {arg: 'prediction', type: 'string'},
        {arg: 'success', type: 'boolean'}
      ]
    }
  );
```

And the way I am calling it is:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d 'container=5c019e748ebd08001351269a&name=img_8' 'http://localhost:3000/api/engine/evaluateone?access_token=vNM60TvRA5OZnhHHmZf3y58xS5MTa3dMyOg81f9bYbm3HCS5aLqev59dDJujzU4o'
```

The permissions are correct and the method can only be accessed by authorised users, hence the access token

I have also discovered that when using the GPU accelerated library of tfjs (tfjs-node-gpu), the method works whereas when using CPU only library (tfjs-node) it does not. The only change made is the library used

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The error message strongly suggests to me that the `"file://`" URL is the problem.

Comment: That url works fine when using the gpu accelerated library, but might be the issue, do you know what the alternative would be?